# How can I override the ToString() method to output a list?

Tags: c#, .net, list, class, overriding

Is it possible to override the ToString() method to output a list?
Here's my code

```
    namespace CircularClass
{
    class InfinitelyCircular
    {

        public class RatsInAShip
        {
            public string RatBreed;
            public string RatWeight;
            public string RatAge;
            public bool HasChildren;
            public List<RatsInAShip> RatChildren;
            public override string ToString()
            {
                return String.Format("RatBreed:{0}\n RatWeight:{1}\n RatAge:{2}\n HasChildren:{3}",RatBreed, RatWeight, RatAge, HasChildren);
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var mu = new RatsInAShip()
                         {
                             RatAge = "100",
                             RatBreed = "RexRat",
                             RatWeight = "200",
                             HasChildren = true,
                             RatChildren = new List<RatsInAShip>()
                         };

            for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                var cu = new RatsInAShip()
                             {
                                 RatAge = "100",
                                 RatBreed = "DwarfRat"+i,
                                 RatWeight = "200",
                                 HasChildren = false
                             };
                mu.RatChildren.Add(cu);
            }

            //Output
                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}, {1}", mu.RatBreed, mu.RatChildren[0]));

        }
    }
}
```

How can I override ToString() to output all the children in a list?

Comment: What do you mean by "list"? Are you talking about the `List` class? Or do you just mean a comma-separated list in a `String`?

Comment: You can't, `ToString()` and any overridden method can only ever return the same type as the parent class (in this case a `string`). Do you mean you want to output a single string with each child on a seperate line?

Comment: this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173154(VS.80).aspx)  may help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you would could output the children in a foreach loop, like this:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.AppendFormat("RatBreed:{0}\n RatWeight:{1}\n RatAge:{2}\n HasChildren:{3}\n",RatBreed, RatWeight, RatAge, HasChildren);
    foreach (RatsInAShip rat in RatChildren)
    {
        sb.AppendFormat("\tRat Child: {0}\n", rat);
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

I haven't compiled this, so please correct me if I made a mistake.
[edit] compiled now... :)

Comment: Note: Abhi, when I run this, I get an exception telling that your RatChildren variable is not set to an instance of an object. You will have to modify the rest of your class to make sure the list is instantiated. But that will require other changes to your program that are not related to 'ToString'.

Comment: So if you cnage the last line in your Main function to:
Console.WriteLine(mu);
Also I added an initializer to the RatsInAShip class definition, like this:
public List<RatsInAShip> RatChildren = new List<RatsInAShip>();
Once that is done, you will see the proper results which is this:
RatBreed:RexRat
 RatWeight:200
 RatAge:100
 HasChildren:True
        Rat Child: RatBreed:DwarfRat0
 RatWeight:200
 RatAge:100
 HasChildren:False

        Rat Child: RatBreed:DwarfRat1
 RatWeight:200
 RatAge:100
 HasChildren:False

        Rat Child: RatBreed:DwarfRat2
 RatWeight:200
 RatAge:100
 HasChildren:False

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you're already overriding the ToString() method on your class... so... use a StringBuilder and a for/foreach loop to construct your output string?

Answer (score 2):

To *output* a list?  As in, return a list?  No.  Two reasons:

1. You can't change the return type of an overridden method.
2. `ToString()` implies that it returns a string.  Returning anything else would be highly unintuitive and invites support problems with the code.

Answer (score 1):

You *can't* change the return type of an overriden method.

You will need to write your own method that returns a list:

```
public IList<string> ToList()
{
  // your code that returns a list of strings
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    string result = "";
    if(RatChildren != null)
      foreach(var x in RatChildren)
        result += String.Format("RatBreed:{0}\n RatWeight:{1}\n RatAge:{2}\n HasChildren:{3}", x.RatBreed, x.RatWeight, x.RatAge, x.HasChildren);

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Saw the edit, you should also get it to do a line break, or other delimiter when appending to the string. Also consider using a `StringBuilder`.

Comment: Grrr, I provide the code for the suggestion of the guy that gets +2 and I get a -1??  undo pls...

Comment: I did a -1 when you had incorrect code. I've now undone my -1.

Comment: (agree, a separator of some sort etc - but let's not do all the guy's work for him, lol)

Answer (score 0):

You can override the `ToString` as you have done already. You could iterate through the elements of the list to output the string of your desire.